# how to access mysql in console

Tags: server, mysql, lamp, xampp

I installed mysql alone with xampp and runing all services successfully, but when i try to login to mysql server using mysql-client it gives the following error.

```
user@user-pc:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql 
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...already running.
user@user-pc:~$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p 
Enter password:  
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

how can i fix this error

Comment: mysql tries to connect via a socket, did you configure mysqld to listen there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to fix above issue by simply replacing /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf file to /etc/mysql/my.cnf

1) First backup the /etc/mysql/my.cnf to some where if some thing goes wrong

```
user@user:~$ cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/Desktop/
```

2) Then copy /etc/mysql/my.cnf file to /etc/mysql/

```
user@user:~$ sudo cp /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/
```

3) Restart the computer

4) Start lampp server

```
user@user:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

5) Then mysql-client will start in console without any errors

```
user@user:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.24 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

I done this in Ubuntu 14.04